# how to modify a row that is read from sql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table in PHP where want modify its cells, by clicking on Update link and it should send the data of the selected row to modify and update

I've been looking for examples but I can't find anything,and very new to php. Any help will be very useful.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo
'

    <form name="frmRow" method="post"   action="update.php?id='.$row['id'].' ">
    <tr>
    <td ><a href="update.php" >Update </a>  </td>
    <td><a href="delete.php">Delete</a>   </td>
    <td >'.$row['name1'].'</td>
    <td >'.$row['name2'].'</td>
    <td >'.$row['name3'].'</td>
    <td >'.$row['id'].'</td>
    </tr>
   </form>


';
}
```

The table is filled with data from a mysql table

and  this is update.php

```
<?php

require_once('config/config.php');

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

    $sql='update TABLE set name1="'.$_POST['name1'].'" , 
    name2=="'.$_POST['name2'].'" , name3=='.$_POST['name3'].'    
    where id='.$_POST['id'].'    ';
    mysqli_query($connect,$sql);0
}

?>
```

but `GET['id']`  and `$_POST` are always empty.

Comment: you might want to look into `FORMS` and `INPUT` types.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Comment: `action=` will only work with a **submit** button. (`type='submit'`).

Comment: You need input elements to post the data from form: `<input type="hidden" name="name1" value="value"/>`
Hidden inputs wont be rendered

Comment: You cannot use get and post in one time.. It depend on your action tag

Comment: @Marty1452 I've never bumbed into problems using both

Comment: @user3647971 ok its just my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I would not echo out your form as a string.  A foreach loop can print plain html and php in the same iteration.  Second, you need to have input boxes.

```
//  You wont need this if you do the while loop the way you original had it
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


<table>
foreach($rows as $row) {
// or your original method while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
<form method="post" action="update.php">
<tr>
   <td><button type="submit">Submit</button>  </td>
   <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
   <td ><input name='name1' value="<?php echo $row['name1']; ?>"></td>
   <td ><input name='name2' value="<?php echo $row['name2']; ?>"></td>
   <td ><input name='name3' value="<?php echo $row['name3']; ?>"></td>
   <td ><input name='id' value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
</form>   
}  

</table>
```

Also remove `action="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'` and just make it `action="update.php'` for both get and post methods.

Note: if there is no value you need to be able handle that while looping through your results

Note:  As some comments have already mentioned, you can not grab from post with `$_GET` and vice versa